# Visual Basic Form Coding (how to set a directory)

Tags: vb.net

Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click

```
    Dim Newline As String
    Newline = System.Environment.NewLine
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\Users\Sang\Desktop\filename.txt", Result1.Lines)
    System.IO.File.AppendAllLines("C:\Users\Sang\Desktop\filename.txt", Result2.Lines)
    System.IO.File.AppendAllLines("C:\Users\Sang\Desktop\filename.txt", values.Lines)


End Sub
```

This is my coding for making a text file on my desktop. However, my friend can not run this code because this code is only for myself as you can see above. I would like to use a folderbroswerdialog to generalize this coding for everyone. To be specific, if a user pressed this button on the form, folder browser should ask him where he wants to save this text file and text file should be saved in the directed folder or desktop. I tried to do it on my own by looking at many youtube videos and resources but I failed. How should I proceed this?

Comment: Always use Environment.GetFolderPath() to find the desktop folder path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Enumeration which contains the ubications of the system's directories that you can retrieve using [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method :

```
Dim DesktopDir As String = 
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
```

Then you can use the [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to properlly combine a directory/file path:

```
Dim OutputFile As String = 
    IO.Path.Combine(DesktopDir, "filename.txt")
```

Then:

```
IO.File.WriteAllLines(OutputFile, "Text Here")
```

Comment: @The Guy with The Hat Yes, I've added some comments with MSDN hyperlinks inside.

Comment: Is there any way to save in the current directory(where the exe file is) as well?

Comment: Yes, See `Application.StartupPath` property on MSDN for more details.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look here for using the FolderBrowserDialog:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx

PERFECTLY great examples there.

Comment: I tried to use that example but it makes an error in my code.. what should I change it from the example to run without an error? (private parts work but public sub and codes below cause error)

Comment: I even copied and paste the whole thing in the different form project to see how it's supposed to turn out but it didn't work as well.

Comment: There has nothing to do an FolderBrowser dialog with the question of the OP.

Comment: Then, what are you suggesting me to do?

Comment: whoever -1 explain yourself. this has everything the OP wants. I would have suggested to use the Environment.GetFolderPath however the OP made it clear he would want to use the FBD instead, which is what I provided. if the code does not work then show the error, what problems do you get? explain clearly and to the full - we are not mind readers